# Firebase with dynamic applicationId

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am maintaining a website where people can customize an Android application and download as an apk file.

I need to implement push notifications. I had it implemented in Google Cloud Messaging before. But I am moving to Firebase now.

The problem is that Firebase is configured with specific application ids through google-services.json configuration file. But I need it to run with automatically generated application ids.

I have already tried to change the id in the configuration file. It compiles, but notifications are not delivered.

Please, can anyone tell me if there is a way to make it work?

**Edit:**
I don't see how my question is related to an Android Datepicker question with nothing to do with Firebase.

Comment: @HossamHassan No, this is not related at all

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way, you need always create new android app per every unique app id in firebase console. Then download and build new app instance with generated 'json'. Unfortunately, firebase does not provide any API for automatization this, and you have to do it manually every time.